# Error in executing Solr query using JNI in C using java class

Tags: java, c, solr, java-native-interface

I have a java class which executes Solr query and prints the output , which is working perfectly well .
I am using EmbeddedSolrServer , snippet is below :

```
    String solrDir = "/Users/TheRoot/Downloads/solr-4.7.0/example/solr/";
    CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(solrDir);
    container.load();
    EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1");
    ModifiableSolrParams solrParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    solrParams.add(CommonParams.Q, "*:*");
    QueryResponse queryResponse = null;
    try {
        queryResponse = server.query(solrParams);
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (SolrDocument document : queryResponse.getResults()) {
        System.out.println(document.getFieldValueMap().toString());
    }
    server.shutdown();
    container.shutdown();
```

But when I try to access main from my C code , it throws error saying :

```
  Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x109fbdfac
```

When I comment out

```
    try {
        queryResponse = server.query(solrParams);
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (SolrDocument document : queryResponse.getResults()) {
        System.out.println(document.getFieldValueMap().toString());
    }
```

error is not thrown .
My C code snippt is below :

```
 EmbeddedSolrExample_Class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "EmbeddedSolrExample");
 main_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, EmbeddedSolrExample_Class, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, EmbeddedSolrExample_Class, main_method, NULL);
```

Although I am able to access and get output from other functions from the java class .

Comment: Got the solution ... The problem was when I was initialing the java vm in C ... I had to add JavaVMOption options;options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/Users/....[all jars]"; etc ...

Comment: Anyone who comes next .. here i posted complete flow  http://randr.svbtle.com/experiment-with-embedded-solr-in-java-and-c